# How to automatically select data for Curve-fitting

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am having trouble trying to automatically generate good fits using the curve fitting tool without a user input. The aim is for just the data to be provided and for it to generate a good fit consistently without me having to tamper with the parameters or the data itself. I am using the following code:

```
# %% Curve fitting

root = tk.Tk(); root.withdraw()  # close the tkinter root window

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()  # open file dialogue box

data = np.loadtxt(file_path, skiprows=0)  # read the data from file
t = data[:, 0]; y_offset = data[:, 1]  # extract the time and data arrays

cutoff = 150
cutoff = cutoff+1
t = t[:cutoff]
y_offset = y_offset[:cutoff]


def myfit(t, a, b, c, phi, ho):                 # define the function
    return a*np.exp(b*t)*np.cos(c*t+phi) + ho


def freq_from_crossings(sig, fs):
    # """Estimate frequency by counting zero crossings"""
    # Find all indices right before a rising-edge zero crossing
    indices = np.nonzero((sig[1:] >= 0) & (sig[:-1] < 0))[0]
    # More accurate, using linear interpolation to find intersample
    # zero-crossings (Measures 1000.000129 Hz for 1000 Hz, for instance)
    crossings = [i - sig[i] / (sig[i+1] - sig[i]) for i in indices]
    # Some other interpolation based on neighboring points might be better.
    # Spline, cubic, whatever
    return fs / np.mean(np.diff(crossings))


# creating sensible guesses
h0 = 0
a0 = int(max(y_offset))
b0 = int((np.log(0.2/a0))/-0.4)
f0 = int(freq_from_crossings(y_offset, Actual_Frame_Rate))
c0 = int(2*np.pi*f0)
phi0 = 0

# perform the fit # [1,-10,100,0,2]
param, param_cov = curve_fit(myfit, t, y_offset, p0=[a0, b0, c0, 0, h0], maxfev=20000)
    
# get the standard deviations of all fit parameters from variance-co-variance matrix
stdevm = np.sqrt(np.diag(param_cov))

# generate the fit line ready for plotting
fitplot = param[0]*np.exp(param[1]*t)*np.cos(param[2]*t+param[3])+param[4]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, y_offset, 'r.', label="data")
plt.plot(t, fitplot, '-', color='blue', label="fit")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("time (seconds)")
plt.ylabel("Displacement from initial height (pixels)")
curvefitting_path = "/Users/harryhat/Desktop/Droplet Experiment/Curve Fitting/"
plt.savefig(curvefitting_path+path_end+' curve fitting.png')
```

The parameters which are roughly calculated are a good approximation however what I have found makes a substantial difference is the data range selected. As shown by the two graphs shown below, the data selected makes a big difference. Both graphs use the same data set but the latters data is cut off, and this makes a big difference with the fit. I was wondering if there was anyway to fix this by sort of detecting that the data isn't fluctuating much? A lot of these graphs need to be to plotted so going through manually would be a lot of work. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the biggest problem is the frequency guess by zero crossings. Obviously there is an offset ( I seems it is not fitted though, which is slightly irritating). The point is: what happens if the amplitude drops below the offset. In that case no zero crossings and hence a quite wrong starting value for the frequency. What about an fft to get the frequency?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a small drift in the data? So instead of just an offset you have `h0 - s * t`?